# How to customize view in [TeXnicCenter] to show full structure of document?

Tags: texniccenter

Whilst using TeXnicCenter I already wondered a couple of times if it was possible to make more levels visible in the structure window? Currently it is showing up to six levels but my project contains more sublevels than that. Will I somehow be able to change that setting or do I have to switch my editor?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I understood the question correctly. what are you asking about: the file depth (e.g. main.tex, subfile.tex., subsubfile.tex, etc.) or the content depth (e.g. chapter, section, subsection, etc.)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. You are right, I did not make myself very clear. I am actually talking about the depth in the structure window you can access to view the structure of your document. My document contains the structure of a book, beginning with \part and ending with some \subsevensection. Now the editor is not able to show me that depth in its overlay. So the question is more related to the editor than to a LaTeX-code.

Comment: I'm not sure if TXC supports this. I use TeXstudio, which does support your scenario. But from what I can see in screenshots, it appears that it can be configured in TXC as well.

Comment: Could you specify that with the screenshots? I still haven't found any setting to increase the number of levels that is shown. Thank you

Comment: ok...I did some research and I've to admit, I couldn't figure out how to change the outline widget to make it show more information about the outlining of a document. unfortunately I couldn't find the screenshot I saw. so I downloaded and tried for myself. and it appears to me, that the outline widget takes its data from the outline commands inside the source code, but disregards paragraph and below. I couldn't change this. to see the difference, i copied my snippet into TeXstudio and in there, the outlining was shown in total, including paragraphs and below. sorry, I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks nevertheless! If I wanted to start using TeXstudio, how would I have to adjust its settings?

Comment: regarding your scenario, I didn't change anything. the widget showed all levels as they were used in the document. download TXS and try see for yourself if it satifies your needs. it sure does for me.

Comment: I tried it, but it also only shows the levels up to subsubsection. Whenever I go deeper, i.e. subthreesection or even further, it will not show up for me. But maybe that's related to my documentclass jurabook?

Comment: Okay, I just had a look into my documentclass. The problem must be related to the class jurabook.cls contained in the juramisc-package. It defines new subsections up to level \subeightsection. Do you - by chance - have any clue if it was possible to correlate those settings in the documentclass to the settings of any editor?

Comment: afraid not.  I think you should update your question regarding this problem.